# Disallow one element from base

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to restrict my `Derived` type to only use one element, not two as the `Base`:

```
<xs:complexType name="Base">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MyElement" />
        <xs:group ref="MyGroup" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Derived">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="Base">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="MyElement" maxOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:group ref="MyGroup" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

So this should validate:

```
<Derived>
    <ElementFromMyGroup />
</Derived>
```

But this should not:

```
<Derived>
    <MyElement />
    <ElementFromMyGroup />
</Derived>
```

Unfortunately my solution is not legal in XSD. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Derived` type is not a restriction of your `Base` type:  there are instances of `Derived` which are not instances of `Base`.

Depending on why you want the two types to be related to each other, you may wish to specify a common supertype for them, with a declaration along these lines:

```
<xs:complexType name="CommonSuperType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="MyElement" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:group ref="MyGroup" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Then define your current two types as restrictions of this common supertype.